# UiPath selector not working in 'Click Button' Activity

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I have the version of UiPath Studio Pro 2020.10.6, and I used Chrome.

I can't find the common Selector on two pages:

- [First case - failed one](https://www.sephora.fr/p/sephora-x-coach---palette-de-fards-a-paupieres-rexy-496442.html)
- [Second case - great one](https://www.sephora.fr/p-sephora_collection_set27.html)

The selectors offered by the tool are the following:

Case 1:

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Sephora X Coach - Palette de fards à paupières Rexy de SEPHORA COLLECTION ≡ SEPHORA' />
<webctrl id='add-to-cart' tag='BUTTON' type='submit' />
```

Case 2:

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Kit maquillage des yeux de SEPHORA COLLECTION ≡ SEPHORA' />
<webctrl id='add-all-to-cart' tag='BUTTON' type='submit' />
```

Removing the title tag does not solve the problem.
The use of wild-cards does not work. [image: see here]

I looked via the "Fuzzy Search":https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/fuzzy-search-capabilities
I did the test in Python of the script of the page for the first case: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python
The result is like in the picture above:[image: see here]
But it's not working too for the first case, since I put the level at 0.1

```
<html app='chrome.exe' title='"+SelectorString+ "' matching:title='fuzzy' fuzzylevel:title='0.3'  /><webctrl id='add-all-to-cart' tag='BUTTON' type='submit' />
```

with

```
SelectorString = "Sephora X Coach"
```

I have no more idea, is the fact that in my first case the button is in a form (when looking at the code of the HTML page) and not in the second case?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you want to select? Not very clear as you say 
    First case - failed one
    Second case - great one
Could you maybe just give image of the buttons?

Comment: My apologies @kwoxer I did not see your question but as you can see the solution actually required the use of regular expression

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, I change the selector like that:

```
<html app='chrome.exe' />
<webctrl id='add[-all]*-to-cart' matching:id='regex' tag='BUTTON' type='submit' />
```

Comment: My apologies @kwoxer I did not see your question but as you can see the solution actually required the use of regular expression